# Total memory decreased when increasing swap file?

Tags: linux, centos, memory

I am running a low-end server with about 1GB RAM and I was trying to optimize my ram. But after increasing my swap file and emptying the buffers, my total ram, judging from `free -m`, have lowered from 1 GB to 660 MB - and I cannot run my applications anymore.

Repro steps:
I have used the commands

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Then, I have tried `swapoff -a` and `swapon -a`

And then I increased my swap file, as described here:
https://www.linux.com/learn/increase-your-available-swap-space-swap-file

I have no idea what lowered my total memory. Could anyone help, please? Thanks in advance!

I am running Centos.

Comment: Can you share the output of 'free -m'?

Comment: http://imgur.com/QTe3zfG <--- screenshot here. The total is 726 now.

Comment: And now it's 660 again...